# Pass SessionID to api.ai through dotnet sdk

Tags: .net, api-ai

This seems very trivial question, but I can't find a way to pass the SessionID through the ApiAi.TextRequest call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, turns out its the sdk is built in a way to work only from client side. [It generates the GUID internally](https://github.com/api-ai/apiai-dotnet-client/blob/master/ApiAiSDK/AIDataService.cs):

```
    public AIDataService(AIConfiguration config)
    {
        this.config = config;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config.SessionId))
        {
            SessionId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            SessionId = config.SessionId;
        }
    }
```

So what I ended up doing is to add the SessionId object to the ApiRequest object:

```
    [JsonProperty("sessionId")]
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
```

Obviously you will need to refactor the methods signatures